# Use Func<T,bool>[] as a parameter list and check the result for each function

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, func, type-parameter

**UPDATED:**
I am trying to write a method to do somes work and before it actually does those works it needs to go through some validations. Those validation varies based on what work it's going to do.

**After some thoughts, I still want to use the same patterns with some minor changes.**
 **Now, I want to make the following code works:**

```
SomeClass:

        public SomeResponse DoSomething<T>(params Func<T, bool>[] validations)
        {
            if(validations.All(v=>v(T))
            {
                some logic..
            }
            return SomeResponse;
        }
```

Usage:

```
       private Func<SomeRequest, bool> ValidateName = r =>
        {return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Name);};
       private Func<SomeRequest, bool> ValidatePhone = r =>
        {return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Phone);};

       var someResponse = SomeClass.DoSomething<SomeRequest>(ValidateName,ValidatePhone);
```

Again, the code currently doesn't work because it's giving me error on

```
if(validations.All(v=>v(T))
```

basically Type parameter is not valid here, and I couldn't find a way to pass in an actual `SomeRequest` object to the Func.

How should I write the code **to loop through all the results** return by the list of functions and make sure they are returning true, as well as **keeping the flexibility of the Type parameter**?

**Answer:**

Found a way to do that, hope this can be helpful:

Simply modify the method definition to :

SomeClass:

```
    public SomeResponse DoSomething<T>(T request, params Func<T, bool>[] validations)
    {
        if(validations.All(v=>v(request))
        {
            some logic..
        }
        return SomeResponse;
    }
```

Then use it like:

```
var someResponse = SomeClass.DoSomething<SomeRequest>(someRequest, ValidateName,ValidatePhone);
```

Please let  me know if there is any other solution.

Comment: You can not cast `Func<NameRequest, bool>` or `Func<PhoneRequest, bool>` to `Func<Request, bool>`. `Func<in T, out TResult>` contravariant by first type parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're almost there!

First note that `Validations` is an array of `Func<Request, bool>` - that is, each item in the array is a *function* which takes a `Request` as a parameter and returns a `bool`.

So in order to get the `bool` out of the `Func`, you need to apply it to a `Request` object. In C#, applying a `Func` to an argument looks just like calling a method. So your LINQ expression will look like this:

```
validations.All(f => f(request))
```

This will return `true` if and only if all of the functions in `validations` return `true` (when applied to `request`).

So your full `if` block will look like this:

```
// I'm just guessing what the code to make a Request object will look like
Request request = resource.GetRequest();

if (!validations.All(f => f(request)))
{
    throw new Exception("Not all of the validations checked out");
}
```

You haven't provided enough context for me to tell you where to get a `Request` object from but I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question a bit to make it more specific. The problem is that the request object is passed when the method get called, like the first function has the NameRequest passed in. they are both the subtype of Request but I am still confused about what object I can use in if (!validations.All(f => f(request))). Could you please explain more in detail?

Comment: I see the problem - you want to pass a `Func<NameRequest, bool>` or a `Func<PhoneRequest, bool>` to a parameter of type `Func<Request, bool>`. Unfortunately, there's no way to do this because `Func` is contravariant in its first parameter. `Func<NameRequest, bool>` is **not** a subtype of `Func<Request, bool>`. (In fact the reverse is true.) This suggests to me that you need to rethink your design. (cont.)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Given a `Request` of a certain type, do we require _all_ the validators in the list to pass? But what happens when I try to use a `NameRequest` but the list contains a validator of `PhoneRequest`s? It makes more sense to me that what you really want to use the one correct validator for the concrete type of `Request` you have. For that you need a virtual method on `Request` (`request.IsValid()`), or if you want to separate the validation code from the request you need to use [the Visitor pattern](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.IuseVisitor).

Comment: Thanks a lot! you did light up my path -- the Visitor pattern! how could I forget it! I need to get some rest I think :p

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding these types correctly, I would think something like this should work:

```
if (Validations.All(v => v(resource)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `params` here, a simple array will do. You can pass an arbitrary number of `Func` objects with an array.

```
public void DoSomething(Resource resource, Func<Request, bool>[] Validations)
```

Anyway, you can easily use LINQ's `All` method to check if all elements of an array satisfy a predicate.

```
if (Validations.All(v => v(resource)))
```